# Confused about drawable folders, images and screen reselution

Tags: android

I'm not sure I understand the point of different drawable folders for images and screen resolution of the device. I want to display the images as there natural size in pixels. But I either get them to small or to big!

I'm doing a game for tablets. I'm using AVD emulator of Nexus 7 with a 7" screen and a resolution of 1280 x 736 pixel. I have a grid of 8 x 8 images. Each image has the size in width and height of 80 pixel. I draw each image with an interval of 80 pixels.

When I place the images in drawable-hdpi it looks OK, but if I place them in drawable-mdpi then they are overlapping each other, but are bigger.

I also has an intro image with the size of 800 x 400, and when I place that in the drawable-hdpi, then the image get so small on the screen! But when I place the image in the drawable-mdpi, then it looks OK. I'm confused, because it's the opposit!

Since my target is for tablets, wouldn't it be enough to have the images in just one drawable folder, but which one is the correct? Is the point with different folders, to have images of different size in width and height in pixel?

I have read a lot about this, but I don't get it! Could someone briefly explain how I should handle this folders, images and resolution to understand it better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even tablets have different densities, see the list [here](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/list-of-android-devices-with-pixel-density-buckets/).

When you place an image in a drawable directory, you are saying, "this image is suitable for devices at this density."

If your image is in -hdpi, and your device is -hdpi, no scaling will occur.

If your image is in -hdpi, and your device is -mdpi, Android will attempt to scale it down.

If your image is in -hdpi, and your device is -xhdpi, Android will attempt to scale it up.

This is what you are seeing when you move the same image from one folder to another. Android is trying to work out what scaling factor to apply, *based on what folder it's in, and what your device's density is.*

You can read more about scaling factors [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

> If no matching resource is available, the system uses the default resource and scales it up or down as needed to match the current screen size and density
>
> The "default" resources are those that are not tagged with a configuration qualifier. For example, the resources in drawable/ are the default drawable resources. The system assumes that default resources are designed for the baseline screen size and density, which is a normal screen size and a medium density. As such, the system scales default density resources up for high-density screens and down for low-density screens, as appropriate.
>
> However, when the system is looking for a density-specific resource and does not find it in the density-specific directory, it won't always use the default resources. The system may instead use one of the other density-specific resources in order to provide better results when scaling. For example, when looking for a low-density resource and it is not available, the system prefers to scale-down the high-density version of the resource, because the system can easily scale a high-density resource down to low-density by a factor of 0.5, with fewer artifacts, compared to scaling a medium-density resource by a factor of 0.75.

Comment: I don't know if it's an error in the list that you gave a link to. For nexus 7 it says tvdpi, I don't have that folder? But I still don't get it!:( Do I have to have images of the same type in both mdpi, hdpi and xdpi? Same pictures or do I have to change the size or what for each folder?

Comment: If you do export to all the folders you definitely have to change the size for each folder. That's the whole point. HOWEVER, you don't even have to put them in each folder. As described above, Android does a fairly good job of auto-scaling. I would suggest - stick to one folder. Make it look good on your device. Then, test on another device/configuration/density. Take it from there. This is how I normally develop.